# Obtain value in json response

Tags: json, regex, jsonpath

How do i write an expression to obtain the value "lastUpdated" in the below json response data

```
{"resourceType":"Parameters","parameter":[{"name":"medication","resource":{"resourceType":"Bundle","id":"956ffe6a-08ed-4cb6-82ca-41065a4a9923","meta":{"lastUpdated":"2020-08-24T19:09:18.5649325+00:00",
```

I have tried this but it does not work:

```
regex("\"lastUpdated\": \"(.*?)\"").saveAs("lastUpdated")
```

this also does not work:

```
jsonPath("$..[?(@.use==\"lastUpdated\")].value").saveAs("lastUpdated"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input is a little cut off but here is what I've got:

```js
myJSONString = '{"resourceType":"Parameters","parameter":[{"name":"medication","resource":{"resourceType":"Bundle","id":"956ffe6a-08ed-4cb6-82ca-41065a4a9923","meta":{"lastUpdated":"2020-08-24T19:09:18.5649325+00:00"}}}]}'
myJSONObject = JSON.parse(myJSONString)
myLastUpdated = myJSONObject.parameter[0].resource.meta.lastUpdated
console.log(myLastUpdated)
```

Basically you convert it from a json object into a javascript object. Then you can just traverse down the tree to your intended target.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot use (I think) use a java function like that. I am using Gatling tool writing scala code and I allready have something that works using it like this: .check(jsonPath("$..[?(@.name==\"KJFeilkode\")].valueCodeableConcept.text").is("OK")) on the same json response body. So maybe I need to construct it somewhat similar? As in .check(jsonPath("$.parameter[0].resource.meta.lastUpdated")].value.saveAs( "lastUpdated" )) ?